# How do I control visibility of global-scope functions in Dart?

Tags: dart, visibility

```
// api.dart

dynamic publicApi(String address, dynamic payload) {
    ...
}

dynamic login(String email, String password) {
  return publicApi('login', {'email': email, 'password': password});
}

// loginPage.dart

import 'api.dart' as api;
...      
final response = await api.login(emailText.text, pwdText.text);
```

How do I make this source file to export only login(), not publicApi()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add _ before function and this do trick for you.

```
dynamic _publicApi(String address, dynamic payload) {
    ...
}
```

more info [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility)